# Why should I "use inline comments sparingly"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, comments

Reading PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments), I see that programmers should "use inline comments sparingly". No reason for this is provided, though.

I wonder why. I really find it much easier to comprehend a program by reading the code with the comments inline, so that I'm not interrupted by comments when I'm actually trying to read and understand the code.

The best case would be to have comments like we do in Word, matched to a certain point in code, but visible only in a side panel. I don't know if there's an IDE with such features.

That being said, the questions:

1. Is there a technical reason, such as loss in performance, to prefer making annotations in block, instead of inline?
2. Will people reading my code be mad about the many inline comments or that's not a big deal, provided that the comments are actually useful.
3. Is there an IDE with a better commenting environment? Maybe a side panel, maybe a .txt file that is bonded with the .py file and show these comments through its UI. Idk, anything.

Reading PEP, Python documentation and tried googling it up. No useful answers.

(Sorry if too bad. Kind of a beginner in Python 3.)

```
guessed_char = len(secret_word)*["_ "]  #  Defines varLIST of STRs, masked version of
                                        #  secret_word, and also the progression
                                        #  shown to the player

answer = len(secret_word)*[""]          #  Defines varLIST of STRs, that will be checked
                                        #  against secret_word (varSTR) through
                                        #  "".join(answer)

guessed_attempts = []                   #  Defines varLIST of STRs, that will store
                                        #  every letter guessed by the player.

enforcou = False                        #  Defines varBOOL, turns True if attempts
                                        #  (varINT) reaches the limit. Ends the game
                                        #  with a loss.

acertou = False                         #  Defines varBOOL, turns True if word is
                                        #  found by player. Ends the game with a win.

pontos = int(100)                       #  Defines varINT, counts points that will be
                                        #  deduced at every failend attempt.Every
                                        #  change to this value must be followed by
                                        #  changes in other parts of this code

                                        #  Asks player for difficulty level
print("Qual nível de dificuldade?\n 1 - 3 tentativas\n 2- 5 tentativas\n 3 - 10 tentativas")
dificuldade = int(input())
if (dificuldade == 1):
    max_attempts = 3                    #  Define varINT, total number of attempts
elif (dificuldade == 2):
    max_attempts = 5                    #  Define varINT, total number of attempts
else:
    print("Vamos jogar no fácil...")
    max_attempts = 10                   #  Define varINT, total number of attempts

attempts = 1                            #  Define varINT, counts the number of attempts

print("".join(guessed_char))            #  Prints the masked version of secret_word
                                        #  (varSTR) that the player is trying to guess

while (not enforcou and not acertou):   #  Conditions for ending the game.

    print(f"Tentativa {attempts} de {max_attempts}") #  Tells player the attempt number

    guess = input("Qual letra? ").lower()   #  Asks for a guess (varSTR)

    guessed_attempts.append(guess)      #  Adds the guess to the guess' storage

    if (guess in secret_word):          #  If the guess is correct

        index = 0                       #  Defines varINT for storing indexes

        for char in secret_word.lower():    #  iterate through every character in
                                            #  secret_word (varSTR)

            if (guess == char):         #  If the guess matches the character

                guessed_char[index] = f"{guess} "   #  Replaces dummy "_ " in
                                                    #  guesed_char (varLIST)
                                                    #  revealling guessed characters
                                                    #  in the masked progresion shown
                                                    #  to the player

                answer[index] = f"{guess}"          #  Replaces dummy with answer

                print(f"Encontrei a letra {char} na posiçao {index}")   #  Prints that something was correct
                print("".join(guessed_char))        #  Prints the update masked word
                pontos += round(100/max_attempts)   #  Adds points
                if("".join(answer) == secret_word): #  Checks if the player won
                    acertou = True                  #  End while cicle if player won
                    print(f"Você ganhou! A palavra era '{secret_word}'!")   #Prints message telling player he/she won
            index += 1                     #  Adds 1 to varINT index, so everything is on track
    else:                                  #  If guess is not correct
        pontos -= round(100/max_attempts)   # Subtracts points
        print("Que pena, você errou...")    #Tells player he missed
        print("".join(guessed_char))        # Print masked word
                                            # Tells player the guesses he already tried, with correct grammar for linstings in portuguese
        print("Você já tentou as letras ", ", ".join(str(e) for e in guessed_attempts[:-1]), " e ", guessed_attempts[-1], ".", sep="")
        attempts += 1                       # Adds 1 to varINT attempts, so the game get closer to end due to loss
    enforcou = attempts == max_attempts+1   # Defines coditions for losing the game
if (enforcou):                              # If losing conditions are met
    print(f"Que pena, você perdeu... A palavra era '{secret_word}'...")    # Print loss message and the word
print(f"Você fez {pontos} pontos.") # Prints the number of points, regardless of winning or losing.
print ("Fim do jogo") # Tells the player the game ended.
```

Comment: I can read code fluently. most of the comments are superflous if you look at the code beside it. `max_attempts = 5` already tells me what it is - no need to `#  Define varINT, total number of attempts` -you can use docstrings to describe what a function/class does. All thos _varXXX_ are boilerplate and not enforded by python so the comment outlives itself if you redefine the var later to be something other. Use speaking variable names, speaking function names and docstrings. Use comments sparingly to document _exceptions from rules_ or _hacks/bugs/todos_ - not to reiterate what your code does.

Comment: It also makes your code artificially "wide", and if you try to keep them lined up, a change in your code could require *all* of them to be shifted further right, which would make the diff between two commits in your revision control system needlessly complex.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple reasoning against inline comments is maximum line length is 79 characters https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17, so you not want to wrap your code around too much to fit inline comments.

Also you have other ways to add comments like docstrings (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) which might cover what the variables do.